# how to append pojos in a json file using jackson library

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm new to jackson library.I've got data to write in a json file periodically.All the current tutorial that I've gone through overwrites the file.

Comment: May be referring to jackson library tutorials might help you out.

Answer (score 5):

I would use  the [Jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for dealing with JSON. The class `ObjectMapper` can convert POJO:s to JSON and vice versa. In addition to that I would use the `java.nio.file.Files` class to handle the file writing as in the example below.

```
// First, define some POJO
public static class Pojo {
    private final String content;

    @JsonCreator
    public Pojo(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}

// This test simply illustrates file writing of JSON objects
@Test
public void testAppendToFile() throws IOException {
    // The ObjectMapper is used to convert between Pojos and JSON (and vice versa)
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // Convert a Pojo to JSON
    final String json1 = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Pojo("This is the content #1"));

    // Write it to the file myfile.json. 
    // The first time the file is created and the content is NOT appended
    Files.write(new File("myfile.json").toPath(), Arrays.asList(json1), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

    // Convert another Pojo to JSON
    final String json2 = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Pojo("This is the content #2"));

    // Write to the file again.
    // The second time the content is appended (due to StandardOpenOption.APPEND)
    Files.write(new File("myfile.json").toPath(), Arrays.asList(json2), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

    // Read the file and verify that there are 2 lines
    final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(new File("myfile.json").toPath());
    Assert.assertEquals(2, lines.size());
}
```