# How to append Object to existing JSON file with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

How do i append an object to an existing JSON file with Jackson?

```
File file = new File("test.json");
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
mapper.writeValue(file, wtf);
```

Answer (score 6):

In your question, "append" can have multiple meanings/solutions depending in which context you place that word. For example:

1. A plain append to a file, ignoring existing JSON structure.
2. Append to an existing JSON array in a file.

   1. Append to an existing JSON array in a file, while the JSON array isn't closed yet.
   2. Append to an existing JSON array in a file, while the JSON array is already closed.

**Solution of example #1:**

```
// File output: {"name":"Foo","age":20} {"name":"Bar","age":30} {"name":"Baz","age":40}
public static void plainAppendExample() {
    File file = new File("u:\\test.json");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        JsonGenerator g = mapper.getFactory().createGenerator(new FileOutputStream(file));

        mapper.writeValue(g, new Person("Foo", 20));
        mapper.writeValue(g, new Person("Bar", 30));
        mapper.writeValue(g, new Person("Baz", 40));
        g.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Each writeValue() appends to the file a plain JSON object, but ignores the previous JSON structure.

**Solution of example #2.1:**

```
// File output: [ {"name" : "Foo", "age" : 20}, {"name" : "Bar", "age" : 30}, {"name" : "Baz", "age" : 40} ]
public static void jsonArrayAppendExample2() {
    try {
        File file = new File("u:\\test.json");
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        SequenceWriter seqWriter = mapper.writer().writeValuesAsArray(fileWriter);
        seqWriter.write(new Person("Foo", 20));
        seqWriter.write(new Person("Bar", 30));
        seqWriter.write(new Person("Baz", 40));
        seqWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Where each write() appends to an existing JSON array in the file, until close() is called.

**Solution of example #2.2:**
I haven't found a solution for this. In this case, the solution should modify the file by replacing the array closing character `]` and then perform the appends.

Or, if performance and memory is not a problem, you could re-read the JSON file to a Java object, then add a new JSON object, and then write to the file again.

**Note:**
Note that I'm not a Jackson expert, so I don't know if my solution is the best solution.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out something similar to 2.2 and found this: https://www.geekyhacker.com/2020/04/07/append-arrays-to-an-existing-json-file-with-jackson/

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what `wtf` is but Jackson will map it for you:

```
class Wtf {
    String  brand;
    boolean stinks;

    public String getBrand() {
       return brand;
    }
    public boolean getStinks() {
       return stinks;
    }
    public void setBrand(String brand) {
       this.brand = brand;
    }
    public void setStinks(boolean stinks) {
       this.stinks = stinks;
    }
}

// From your code...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Insert
Wtf wtf = new Wtf();
wtf.setBrand("Noodle");
wtf.setStinks(true);

ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
mapper.writeValue(file, wtf);
```

Is this your question?

Comment: Won't that just overwrite the file instead of adding the wtf object to existing json data inside test.json?

Comment: Yes.  from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653044/how-to-append-pojos-in-a-json-file-using-jackson-library the solution is to utilize `mapper.writeValueAsString` to obtain a String then APPEND it to the file as an Array.