# How to store java objects in json file?

Tags: java, json

I intend to store multiple java objects into a JSON file but I got no clue how to do so. 
That's my code :

```
private static final String JSONFILEPATH = "config.json";

public void addSavefile(Savefile sf){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try{
        mapper.writeValue(new File(JSONFILEPATH), sf);
    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But it works just once, after I try to add more objects it just deletes the last one stored and replaces it with the new one.

Comment: Yep, that's how it works. You'd need to read the file first and append the data, then write it all. Otherwise you'd also create invalid json. Consider using a database instead of files.

Comment: Could you give me an example of append? I cannot use databases for this task

Comment: it seems its a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981487/how-to-append-object-to-existing-json-file-with-jackson

Comment: the first response doesn't work at all, the json that you get from it it's invalid and the second one I cannot try, it says that seqWriter its an invalid refference

Comment: Your code keeps writing a new file. What you need to do is addcode that tries to read the file and append to it and only create a file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Still, how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest, that you never write a single `Savefile` object in your file but already start with a `List<Savefile>`. Then it is much easier to append further objects to this list with the following steps:

1. Read your yet-created file
2. Deserialize the contents to a `List<Savefile>`
3. Write the now augmented list back to the file (deleting all the content which yet exists in this file)

Put into code (simplified with a `Test` object instead of your `Savefile`) this would look like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        File file = new File("/home/user/test.json");

        // step 1 – assuming you already habe or wrote a file with empty JSON list []
        List<Test> tests = mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<List<Test>>(){});

        // step 2
        tests.add(new Test(4));

        // step 3
        mapper.writeValue(file, tests);
    }

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Test {
        int a;
    }
```

Annotations come from Lombok.

> The trick with `new TypeReference<List<Test>>(){}` helps you to deserialize objects with generics. Keep in mind that before starting you either have to have a file with an empty JSON array or you skip the first step at all.

Comment: could you provide me an example code please? I really have no clue how to do so in json

Comment: This is the error message that I get from this code
https://pastebin.com/fZ38YAcA

Comment: How does your file look like? Please add it to your quesion. The code above assumes a yet-created file with a list of objects or an empty list to start with.

Comment: at the moment my file it's empty

Comment: Then just add an empty array like `[]`. I've elaborated a little bit more on the pre-conditions and generic deserialization in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190901/discussion-between-mle-and-terchil-marian).